# Many shipping methods configured and would like to select a default one

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods

I have various shipping methods configured and would like to select a default one.

I don't have a clue where to start on magento 2

Answer (score -1):

Go to admin(shop back-end), click the below path.

> STORES->Configuration->Sales->Shipping Methods

.

Go to Free shipping, Enabled option in `Yes`. Other wise all the shipping method are select enabled in `No`.

Please refer the screen shot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks sankar. listing 4 shipping method in frontend, only one option should be select by default. is that possible. please guide me

Comment: please help me anyone

Comment: Dear magento 2 developers, am new to magento. I have listing 4 shipping method in cart page, it should be select by default one method. Please help me friends

Comment: I have check this issue. I have find this issue, after send the comments

Comment: Hi Sankar, Did you get any solution ?